# Tilde not working in gnome-terminal

Tags: shell, gnome-terminal

I figured out recently that my '~' character doesn't work in gnome-terminal:

-it works in ANY application I can run (sublime text, emacs, gedit, nano...)
-it works on TTYs (ctrl+alt+FX)
-it works on xterm, xfce4-terminal etc.

-it doesn't work in gnome-terminal. I reinstalled it, still doesn't work
-it doesn't work in dash, when launched from gnome-terminal

- I use zsh, I tried to launch it with a brand new .zshrc since I have quite a lot of keybindings in it and it still doesn't work.
  Oh, and also, when I run 'sed -n l' and try a '~', nothing shows up, so no key binding from anywhere, I guess...

I'm kind of out of ideas right now, and hope you could help me?

Regards

Comment: Does *anything* happen when you press it in gnome-terminal? Have you checked the hotkeys for the menus in gnome-terminal? If you run `read -n 1` and then hit `~` does read exit and return you to the prompt?

Comment: Hi and thanks for you answer, but nope, nothing :(.

Comment: So `read` doesn't see it? Then if that works in a different terminal (in the same X session) then gnome-terminal is stealing it and you get to find out why. Look at the shortcuts listed in the menus for starters.

Comment: Damn yeah, you're right!... next-terminal shortcut was set on the tilde character... Thanks for your answer, problem solved :)

Comment: What does this command return: `bind -p | grep '~'`

Answer (score 1):

If other terminals in the same X session are seeing the keypress and things running in gnome-terminal are the only things that can't then gnome-terminal is grabbing the keypress.

You can confirm this by running `read -n 1` in gnome-terminal and hitting <kbd>~</kbd>. If you get the prompt back then the shell saw it. If you don't it didn't.

If it doesn't then you need to see what in gnome-terminal is grabbing it. Check the shortcuts listed in the menus first.

Comment: the shortcuts was it for me - it was set to bring up menu on alt press